# I dont understand what column ORA-01779 is refering too

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, oracle12c

I have a table with POI, you can have multiple POI on each city.

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f61d7b118fd9d59501cadaf0232f213)**

```
CREATE TABLE POI
    ("poi_id" int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, 
     "city_id" int,
      PRIMARY KEY("poi_id")
);
```

Now there were some changes on the cities polygons and now have to reassign some POI

```
CREATE TABLE newCities
    ("city_id" int, "new_city_id" int)
;
```

**DATA**

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO POI ("poi_id", "city_id")
         VALUES (10, 1)
    INTO POI ("poi_id", "city_id")
         VALUES (11, 1)
    INTO POI ("poi_id", "city_id")
         VALUES (12, 2)
    INTO POI ("poi_id", "city_id")
         VALUES (13, 2)
    INTO POI ("poi_id", "city_id")
         VALUES (14, 5)         
SELECT * FROM dual
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO newCities ("city_id", "new_city_id")
         VALUES (1, 100)
    INTO newCities ("city_id", "new_city_id")
         VALUES (2, 200)
    INTO newCities ("city_id", "new_city_id")
         VALUES (3, 200)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

When I do a JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM  poi p 
JOIN newCities nc
  ON p."city_id" = nc."city_id";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+
| poi_id | city_id | city_id | new_city_id |
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+
|     10 |       1 |       1 |         100 |
|     11 |       1 |       1 |         100 |
|     12 |       2 |       2 |         200 |
|     13 |       2 |       2 |         200 |
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

But when I try to do the update but got the error:

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT p.*, nc."new_city_id"
    FROM  poi p 
    JOIN newCities nc
      ON p."city_id" = nc."city_id"
) t
SET t."city_id" = t."new_city_id";
```

I know `city_id` isn't a PK but the row is match with a row including a PK. So why isn't working?

I know I can do a sub query to get the value:

```
UPDATE poi p
SET "city_id" = COALESCE((SELECT "new_city_id" 
                          FROM newCities c 
                          WHERE c."city_id" =  p."city_id")
                        , p."city_id");
```

But still want to know what cases the UPDATE JOIN would work because looks like only can work to update the PK:

Answer (score 1):

After doing the sample test decide try creating a PK on the second table and works:

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc45d7adc949ab237bd12d7a23dcaab6)**

```
CREATE TABLE newCities
    ("city_id" int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, 
     "new_city_id" int,
     PRIMARY KEY("city_id") 
);
```